# UPNP/DLNA Stack

Tags: upnp

I would like to select an UPnP Stack for my DLNA support in my Media Box.

Which Open source is the best one?

rgds,
Th

Answer (score 1):

I'm somewhat happy with [minidlna](http://sourceforge.net/projects/minidlna/). Last I checked, it was the only server that uses file system notification (libinotify on Linux) instead of polling a directory. I just hated hearing my drives going every five minutes.